# How to use post-commit hook on remote repository created on local computer?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

i am having two laptops master and slave, i created a local git repository on slave and i want to trigger jenkins job on master once a commit is made on the slave repository. the job should be processed on master not slave.

i used a post-commit hook script and added that file into the hook directory of the repository located on slave, the post-commit file contains this script

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=file://D:\Devops\Scripting_and_Projects\Learn_By_Projects\2_Post_commit_hook_on_local_repository_done_again\my_repo"
```

and i replaced the localhost with the master laptop IP, adding that those two laptops are connected locally on the same network.

info about my jenkins project created on master laptop:

the project git repository URL is `ssh://Zeid@MySlaveLaptopIP/~/Desktop/bareRepo`.
i added the ssh credentials correctly and made sure to run the build and it successfully cloned the remoted repo and build its project using maven.

Then i tried to commit something new from the slave laptop to the slave repository (locally) using git bash but the triggering is not executed on jenkins master laptop.

Is there something that i am missing , or the script is not designed for remotely access by the master ?
Should i use another Script ?

Comment: Is a Jenkins agent running on the slave laptop on port 8080?

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: Could any one able to get this working?